# Adding up values in a list

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I have a little question. How do I do to sum up all the numbers in a list packs? For example:
List 1 is :

```
0.03326
0.02712
0.02178
0.01918
0.01751
0.01671
0.01602
0.0156
0.01549
0.01543
0.01568
0.01625
0.01658
0.01732
0.0178
0.01827
0.01855
0.01895
0.01949
0.02017
0.0211
0.02213
0.0236
0.02753
0.04504
0.09489
0.10131
0.11255
```

I want to sum up all the numbers.

Comment: [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

Comment: Specify, input data type of list, maybe try to write some code, that have to do your task. Begin to solve your problem yourself, we'll help.

Answer (score 6):

Use `std::accumulate`. It will return the arithmetic sum of all the elements in the list.

```
double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(list), std::end(list), 0.0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the propositions. I found an easier method by try and error.

        double result = sum(myList());
        Info <<"sum is: "<< result<< endl;

Comment: @choformarius With this method you don't have to define your own `sum` function.

Comment: I wouldn't consider writing the function myself easier than using the function provided by the Standard Library specifically for this purpose. Also, do yourself a favour, and stop using [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/).

Answer (score 1):

Do the same like following:

```
double sum=0;
for (std::list<double>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it){
    sum+=*it;
}
```

Hope it may help you :)

Comment: I am wondered why someone give downvote on my answer, is there anything wrong in my answer, please comment then, I want to learn, not to earn point :)

Comment: I think someone gave you a downvote probably because the numbers in OP's list are of type `double` whereas you declare `int sum`

Comment: @MustakimurRahman: then, edit you answer and give the downvoter the chance to undo his vote.

Comment: okay, I did it :) but not for upvote, to give a correct answer :D
Thanks @MM.

Comment: @MustakimurRahman: I wasn't the down-voter anyway +1 for your attention to comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `std::list`,

```
double total = 0;
for (std::list<double>::const_iterator iterator = list1.begin(), end = list1.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) {
    total += *iterator;
}
return total;
```